# Position div to first place - stack like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ser of divs that are created, but only showed when a boolean value is true, it works fine, but if i have two divs and maximize it, that div maximize below the first div, and so on, each div maximize where it is created on html. I want to, when maximize onde div, it passes to first place, above first.

I've made a fiddle, that mimics the funtion now, on that fiddle, for example, i want to click on div#3 and it goes above div#1, then click on div#4 and  goes above div#3, that was in above div#1.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwpCF/112/

Basically, whenever I click on a div, I want it to go on top of all other.

My code of divs are:

**DIV1**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <div class="card-header">
            <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" data-ng-model="barChart" ngbTooltip="{{'chartType' | translate}}">
            //options
            </select>
            <i class="fa fa-expand icons topright" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#timeline1" ngbTooltip="{{'Expand' | translate}}">
            </i>
        </div>
    </h4>
    <div class="card-block">
        <canvas id="barChart" [hidden] = "!barChartSelected"></canvas>
        <canvas id="chart2" [hidden] = "!chart2Selected"></canvas>
        <canvas id="rdr" [hidden] = "!radarChartSelected"></canvas>
        <canvas id="pp1" [hidden] = "!pp1ChartSelected"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="timeline1" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div>
```

**##DIV2**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <h4 class="panel-title">
     <div class="card-header">
        <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" data-ng-model="barChart" ngbTooltip="{{'chartType' | translate}}">
            //options
        </select>
        <i class="fa fa-expand icons topright" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#timeline2" ngbTooltip="{{'Expand' | translate}}">
        </i>
        </div>
    </h4>
    <div class="card-block" [hidden] = "!visibleDiv1">
        <canvas id="barChart_2" [hidden] = "!barChartSelected2"></canvas>
        <canvas id="chart2_2" [hidden] = "!chart2Selected2"></canvas>
        <canvas id="rdr_2" [hidden] = "!radarChartSelected2"></canvas>
        <canvas id="pp1_2" [hidden] = "!pp1ChartSelected2"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="timeline2" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div>

##DIV3 and ##DIV4 are lookalike ##DIV1 and ##DIV2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prependTo`

```
$("#source").prependTo("#destination");
```

It inserts every element in the set of matched elements to the beginning of the target.

> Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/).

Working snippet:

```js
$("#div1").click(function() {
  $("#div1").prependTo($("#main"));
});

$("#div2").click(function() {
  $("#div2").prependTo($("#main"));
});

$("#div3").click(function() {
  $("#div3").prependTo($("#main"));
});
```

```css
.sorteable {
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1" class="sorteable">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="sorteable">Div2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="sorteable">Div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant use prependTo beacause it's going to prepend always on the same destination.. like, always on top of div#1, but if i have div#2, on top of div#1, the next one are going to between them...

Comment: PrependTo will be always going to the same destination. That's true. But if the destination is the main container itself, the clicked div will always be on top of the others.

Comment: I added a snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thank you my friend!! thank you very much!! this solves me some problems!! +1

Comment: I’m glad it helped you. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

How is this (comments by the lines I have added) - I have used closest to get the container and prepend to move the container to the top.

```js
$('.panel-title').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this), // this is the title
    $column = $this.closest('.col-md-6'); // this is the full item

  // Find parent with the class that starts with "col-md"
  // Change class to "col-md-3"
  $this.closest('[class^="col-md"]')
    .toggleClass('col-md-6 col-md-12')
    // Find siblings of parent with similar class criteria
    // - if all siblings are the same, you can use ".siblings()"
    // Change class to "col-md-2"
    .siblings('[class^="col-md"]')
    .removeClass('col-md-3')
    .addClass('col-md-6');

  $column.parent().prepend($column) // prepend the column to the parent - moves it to the top

});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwpCF/142/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pete, the Goediaz's answer gave me the solutions i needed, but yours are fine too..